# ssh then once connected ssh to another server and execute commands and exit both

Tags: ssh, remote

I'm trying to make a bash that SSH's into one server and SSH into another once in, and execute commands on my second server and exit both of them after.

so far I got

```
ssh user@example.edu "ssh user@example2.edu; cd Dirk; source venv/bin/activate; python app.py; exit; exit;"
```

but it seems that I can't execute commands for the second server I ssh'ed into from the first. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run just `ssh user@host` without a command given as an
argument, as in your nested call, ssh will start a shell and wait for
commands to be typed in.

Piping commands into `ssh host1 ssh host 2` should work. To use the
same example as in your question:

```
echo "cd Dirk; source venv/bin/activate; python app.py" \
| ssh user@example.edu ssh user@example2.edu
```

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -t` is maybe your solution

```
ssh user@example.edu -t "ssh user@example2.edu -t 'cd Dirk; source venv/bin/activate; python app.py; exit; exit;'"
```